# ActionBarSherlock Gradle dependency from maven conflict with androidsupportv4

Tags: android, maven, gradle, actionbarsherlock

I have imported successfully from Maven Repository the com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0 and com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0. But when i try to import

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
```

it doesnt import and also if i try to run the application i get a similar error to: 
[Multiple dex files define Android studio error when trying to import Google Maps into Google Maps project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24089002/multiple-dex-files-define-android-studio-error-when-trying-to-import-google-maps)

I dont get the point here why the action bar sherlock library is not imported correctly even that the maven repository is added to dependency correctly .

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/ in android studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264223/multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-v4-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved. I found out the solution by changing build.gradle of my app and adding the @aar part in the compile section of actionbarsherlock

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
}
```

This solved the problem and i found out the solution reading this:

https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/ApkLib